# Problem converting a string to a Date Object

Tags: swift

I have a DatePicker View, When the user clicks a UITextField, it show the DatePicker, which the user can of course, pick a date.
The problem is, when I'm trying to convert the String, to be a date object, I get nothing, so I cannot compare two dates for example.

```
    func checkDate(){

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: Locale.current.identifier)
    dateFormatter.timeZone = .current
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yy"

    guard let startDate = mView.startDateTextField.text else { return }
    print("DATE: \(startDate)")

    guard let startDateFromString = dateFormatter.date(from: startDate) else { return } //I think it returns here.
    //Won't get here.
    print("DATE: \(startDate)")

    guard let endDate = mView.endDateTextField.text else { return }
    guard let endDateFromString = dateFormatter.date(from: endDate) else { return }

    if startDateFromString.compare(endDateFromString) == ComparisonResult.orderedDescending{
        print("Start date cannot be greater than end date.")
    }
}
```

I tried to debug, and the break point does gets to startDateFromString line, but from theres "jumps" outside, so I guess it won't get the Date from the string and returns.

I just can't figure out why.

EDIT: This is where I set the TextField Text to be the date chosen from the DatePicker.

```
    @objc func datePickerValueChanged(sender: UIDatePicker){
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
    dateTextField.text = dateFormatter.string(from: sender.date)

}
```

Comment: What is the actual value of `startDate`?

Comment: It can be everything from the DatePicker, for example Mar 1, 2019

Comment: 1. Show your code for updating the text field with the selected date from the date picker. 2. Why aren't you keeping track of the selected `Date` instead of trying to parse variable format strings?

Comment: I added the code you requested, and I use the same DatePicker for both, start and end date, so I didn't think about it. but your solution sounds really simple and great. I'll try, just getting the date from the Picker itself and not from the Textfield.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using wrong dateFormat. Check your dateFormat from [here](https://nsdateformatter.com)

For example if your dateString is "Mar 1, 2019", you have to use it as dateFormat "MMM d, yyyy"

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM d, yyyy"
```